# Stanford CoreNLP Not Respecting Overrides

Tags: java, nlp

I've modified several of the files used by CoreNLP for Coreference Resolution. It doesn't appear to be using that list. Has anyone had success in overriding their base dcoref dictionaries?

Here is my code to get the CorefChain:

```
public class CorefChains {

    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    public CorefChains() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("dcoref.male","male.unigrams.txt");
        props.put("dcoref.female","female.unigrams.txt");
        props.put("dcoref.animate","animate.unigrams.txt");
        props.put("dcoref.inanimate","inanimate.unigrams.txt");
        props.put("dcoref.demonym","demonyms.txt");
        props.put("dcoref.neutral","neutral.unigrams.txt");
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        this.pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    }

    public Map<Integer, CorefChain> getCoreferences(String str) {
        Annotation document = new Annotation(str);
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
        return graph;
    }
}
```

(I have also tried putting the dcoref properties after the pipeline properties.)

Here is what Eclipse's debugger is showing me (I removed Malta from inanimatite.unigrams.txt, neutral.unigrams.txt, and demonyms.txt. I added it to female.unigrams.txt and animate.unigrams.txt).

[image: Eclipse Debugger]